# Unable to verify the element using protractor Chai

Tags: node.js, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I tried to validate the element using the below format, but unable to execute.

chai declaration in SD:

> > var chai = require('chai');
> >
> > var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
> >
> > var expect = chai.expect;
> >
> > chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

Element definition => **searchResult : element(by.className('class_name'))**

> Code => **(searchResult.isPresent()).should.equal(true);** & error message => **"Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined"**
>
> Code => **expect(searchResult.isPresent()).toBe.equal(true);** & error message => **"Invalid Chai property: toBe. Did you mean \"to"**
>
> Code => **expect(searchResult.isPresent()).to.equal(true);** & error message => **"expected { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) } to equal true"**

could anyone help me to find the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CucumberJS + Protractor + Chai + Chai-as-promised you should write you expectation as following

```
expect(searchResult.isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

You need to add the `eventually` because you are working with promisses

Comment: Thanks for the Help... If you have any link where can I find the element verification and assertion for Chai.

Comment: What to you exactly want to know?

Comment: Link for Chai as promised page - https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/